# Rancher MongoDB Replica Set expose the master

Tags: mongodb, rancher

I've installed MongoDB Replica set from the Rancher catalog and that starts up fine. The next logical thing to do is expose the master so I can configure and use it. I've seen that I could expose 27017 TCP port with a load balancer but then that will round robin instead of having affinity to the mongo master.

Is there a way in Rancher to expose just the master?

Comment: I couldn't figure this out either.  All of mongodb instances are exposed on the private network so I just collected up their IPs and entered a connection string in the form of `mongodb://{privateip1}:27017,{privateip2}:27017,{privateip3}:27017morpheus-dev`  I am assuming there is a better way to do this

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't be ideal because you'll be using that port on all those hosts. The best way I figured was setting up HAProxy to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using HAProxy for this as per this [article](https://blog.danman.eu/mongodb-haproxy/) that outlines this approach:

```
listen mongodb_cluster
 bind 10.0.0.10:27017
 option tcp-check
 # MongoDB Wire Protocol
 tcp-check send-binary 3a000000 # Message Length (58)
 tcp-check send-binary EEEEEEEE # Request ID (random value)
 tcp-check send-binary 00000000 # Response To (nothing)
 tcp-check send-binary d4070000 # OpCode (Query)
 tcp-check send-binary 00000000 # Query Flags
 tcp-check send-binary 61646d696e2e # fullCollectionName (admin.$cmd)
 tcp-check send-binary 24636d6400 # continued
 tcp-check send-binary 00000000 # NumToSkip
 tcp-check send-binary FFFFFFFF # NumToReturn
 # Start of Document
 tcp-check send-binary 13000000 # Document Length (19)
 tcp-check send-binary 10 # Type (Int32)
 tcp-check send-binary 69736d617374657200 # ismaster:
 tcp-check send-binary 01000000 # Value : 1
 tcp-check send-binary 00 # Term

tcp-check expect binary 69736d61737465720001 #ismaster True

option tcpka
 option tcplog
 server mongo-node-01 10.0.0.11:27017 check inter 2000
 server mongo-node-02 10.0.0.12:27017 check inter 2000
```